# What does "make an implication" mean?

Tags: meaning

I did not make an implication, I made a statement, and I made the statement based on the testimony of the president of the corporation.

Comment: Idiomatically, native speakers would almost never *make an implication* - we normally just ***imply** [something]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Instead of saying "Anthony made an implication that ...", native speakers would just say "Anthony implied that ...", is my understanding correct?

Comment: @PutBere: That is *exactly* what I meant, yes.

Comment: There's a well-known "conversation" that goes something along the lines of A: *Do what I say, or bad things will happen*. B: *Is that a threat?* A: *That's not a threat, it's a promise*. Where it's also perfectly natural for B to say *Are you threatening me?* - but you'll probably *never*  come across any version of this interaction where A: echos that continuous form back by replying ***I'm not threatening you, I'm promising you.***

Comment: ...equally, B: might feasibly say *Are you making a threat?* But A would never say *I'm not making a threat, I'm making a promise.*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Your answer is very informative. Thank you. Is it probably because the subject of the sentence is someone rather than something? In other words, the use of "it makes an implication" is more common than the use of "I makes an implication".  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @PutBere: I'm afraid not! :) The sequence ***it makes an/the implication*** gets no relevant hits at all in Google Books. I'll post an actual answer (what I want to say won't fit in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning  here is this one
[Macmillan "implication"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/implication)
"something that you suggest is true, although you do not say it directly"

The person speaking in that quote has been accused of making an implication, that is, implying something indirectly.  His answer is that he wasn't making an implication, but a direct statement.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow rephrase it? Or is there a synonym for "make" here?

Comment: One could say simply, "I was not implying [anything], I made a statement...". (By the braces, I mean that "anything" is optional.)

Answer (score 2):

In the context of conversations, an ***implication*** refers to some "assertion" that's not ***explicitly*** stated, but which a speaker / writer would expect the audience / reader to understand anyway.

Here's [a potentially useful NGram...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20*%20the%20implication&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=30&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Che%20%2A%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhe%20resented%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20realized%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20saw%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20understood%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20resents%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20rejected%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20caught%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20denied%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20drew%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20left%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Che%20*%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhe%20resented%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20realized%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20saw%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20understood%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20resents%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20rejected%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20caught%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20denied%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20drew%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhe%20left%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...from which you'll see that all the common verbs identifying the relationship between subject and object involve him ***receiving*** the implication - none of them are about him ***producing*** an implication.

---

TL;DR: Idiomatically, native speakers almost never ***make** an implication* - we normally just ***imply** [whatever implication is meant].*

Comment: Thank you. How about [make an implication,make any implication](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+an+implication%2Cmake+some+implication%2Cmake+any+implication&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20an%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20any%20implication%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmake%20an%20implication%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20any%20implication%3B%2Cc0)